# Define a function for which $f'(3)$ exists and $f''(3)$ doesn't exist

Tags: integration, derivatives

The task is to define a function for which $f'(3)$ exists and $f''(3)$ doesn't. My idea is: a function doesn't have a derivative at a point if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0-}{f'(x)\neq \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0+}{f'(x)}}$. Therefore if $f'(x)=|x-3|$, $f''(3)$ won't exist. I'll make $f'(x)=2|x-3|$, so that the original function looks better. If I integrate $2(x-3)$, I'll get $x^2-6x=x(x-6)$, so in order to preserve the module, I will define $f(x)=x|x-6|$. This solution is based on intutition and I'm not even sure it works. What is the formal way to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't like your integration of $2|x-3|$. Wouldn't $(x-3)|x-3|$ be better ;-)

Comment: There are other scenarios in which a derivative can fail to exist.  There is not a unique, correct answer.

Comment: If $0<x<6$ then $f(x)=x(6-x)$ which has derivative of all orders at $x=3.$

Comment: You can adapt what you've thought about here for higher derivatives pretty easily! Absolute values are good for exploring differentiability/non-differentiability.

Comment: If you are simply looking for an example of such a function, you can look at $f(x)=(x-3)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Could someone show me how to write a solution mathemathically correct, please?

Comment: @Cyclops Yes, I am looking for an example but I need to explain why I chose it and how I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is great. But the integration is not. We could rather do the following:

$$f(x)=\int_3^x 2|t-3|\mathrm{d}t$$
If $x > 3$, we have that:
$$f(x)=\int_3^x 2(t-3)\mathrm{d}t=(x-3)^2$$
And if $x < 3$, we have that:
$$f(x)=\int_{3}^x -2(t-3)\mathrm{d}x=-(x-3)^2$$
So:
$$f(x)=\text{sgn}(x-3) (x-3)^2 = |x-3|(x-3)$$

Comment: Thank you. If I define $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$. would that also work?

Comment: @DanielHalachev No. The problem is that the derivative itself does not exists at $x=3$.